# Adding value depending on dictionary value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary like this,

`SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES = {
    'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4, 'g': 2, 'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8, 'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 10, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10
}`

Now, say I have a variable like this.

`letter = 'i'`

I want to add the corresponding value to the variable score. So since letter is equal to i, then score should equal 1

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: I think he wants the opposite: add it to some imaginary `score` variable.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Then he needs to be more specific, I think

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: furthermore use `+=` on a `get` will **not** update the dict. It will probably throw an error.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That was an update I wrongly posted, considering the lack clarity in the Q. I need a break tho...

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary values are accessed using `dictionary_name[key]`.  So in this case:

```
score+=SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[letter]
```

You also need to assign `score` to something before you do this:

```
score=0
```

You might find it useful to read the documentation on dictionaries: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

```
SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES = {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 3, 'e': 1, 'd': 2, 'g': 2, 'f': 4, 'i': 1, 'h': 4, 'k': 5, 'j': 8, 'm': 3, 'l': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 1, 'q': 10, 'p': 3, 's': 1, 'r': 1, 'u': 1, 't': 1, 'w': 4, 'v': 4, 'y': 4, 'x': 8, 'z': 10}

>>> SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES['i']
1
>>> SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES['z']
10
```

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly** you need to know [how python plays with dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)- the question you asked in very simple thus people are downvoting!

**Answering you question:**

You have the following code in mind and struggling for the rest. I will be answering them accordingly under your statements.

```
SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES = {
    'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4, 'g': 2, 'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8, 'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 10, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10
}
letter = 'i'
```

In python to get value for a corresponding key it work like `dictionary[key]`, which gives the output.

So for your problem if we do `SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[letter]`, its the same as doing `SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES['i']` where `'i'` is the key and we will get `1` as output.

Hence for `SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[letter]` we get `1` as output!

> I want to add the corresponding value to the variable score. So since letter is equal to i

Assigning the corresponding value to the variable score is `score = SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[letter]`

> then score should equal 1

and we know now for sure that the value of `score` is `1`. Don't we?

For `SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[letter]` value is `1` when `letter= 'i'` thus `score` is `1`